# The report has no tables

Tags: .net, vb.net, crystal-reports, windows-forms-designer

```
Private Sub frmReportExpenses_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

Dim objDatasetExpence As New dSetExpences   // dataset object named as dSetExpences
Dim objRptExpence As New rptExpences       // Crystal report object
Dim MyCommand As New OleDbCommand()
Dim MyConnection As OleDbConnection
Dim myDA As New OleDbDataAdapter()

Try
    Dim connstring As String = "D:\HMSProjects\SMS\SMS\bin\Debug\"
    MyConnection = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + connstring + "msautoconfig.mdb;")
    MyConnection.Open()
    MyCommand.Connection = MyConnection

    MyCommand.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM expences"
    MyCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text
    myDA.SelectCommand = MyCommand

    myDA.Fill(objDatasetExpence, "expences")
    objRptExpence.SetDataSource(objDatasetExpence)   // error here (Report has no Table)
    CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = objRptExpence
Catch ex As Exception

End Try

Me.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized
End Sub
End Class
```

This code show error `"Report has no tables"`
i want to show crystal report using Access 2003 Database pragmatically. blank report is added in project and trying to fill it DataSet object, any suggestion or correction in above code.

Answer (score 1):

Ya, you added the values of DataAdapter to a table in the dataset `objDatasetExpence` with name `"expences"` and you are not pointing the datasource of report object to the datatable inside the dataset. Change your code as follows and try again

```
objRptExpence.SetDataSource(objDatasetExpence.Tables(0)) 
          (or)
objRptExpence.SetDataSource(objDatasetExpence.Tables("expences"))
```

When you dint assign a Datasource to the Database Fields of the Report the same error will come "The report has no tables". See the below Figure and also see the next image where I dint assigned a database fields to the report and the same error I got[image: Setting Database Fields][image: Actuall Error]

Comment: yes i also modify the code as you suggest me, but it again show same type of error while objRptExpence have table of expences, i see it in debugger mode

Comment: Can you pass the code which you modified for the second time.

Comment: myDA.Fill(objDatasetExpence, "expences")
            objRptExpence.SetDataSource(objDatasetExpence.Tables("expences"))
            CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = objRptExpence

Comment: Finally, I got your mistake. May be you dint assign any datatable from the database to the Database Fields of the Report right.

Comment: But my brother i do same coding using sqlclient i mean using sqlserver database and its object then it worked but wnen i moved to Access 2003 database using its connection object then i receive that error

Comment: If you change from sqlserver database to Access 2003 directly in codebehind, before that you should redirect the database Fields of the Report to the Access.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3392/discussion-between-kalyan-and-saman-zia)

Comment: No i do not want to change access 2003 to sqlserver, ok finally Suggest me best solution, i am very thankful to you

Comment: You dont change to sqlserver, but ensure that the Report Database Fields which I have shown in the first figure is correctly set to access 2003 or not